# How to optimize oracle query with 'merge join cartesian' in the plan?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization

Query:

```
select max(b.counter) as counter,
       b.m_group,
       b.m_code,
       a.s_id,
       s.id_sk
  from tbl_various a, tbl_map b, tbl_sheet s
 where coalesce(b.part, a.part) = a.part
   and coalesce(b.nums, to_number(a.nums)) = a.nums
   and coalesce(b.interc, a.interc) = a.interc
   and coalesce(b.segment, a.segment) = a.segment
   and coalesce(b.acountry, a.acountry) = a.acountry_midas
   and coalesce(b.orig_name, a.orig_name) = a.orig_name
   and coalesce(b.fact, a.fact) = a.fact
   and b.sect is not null
   and s.m_code = b.m_code
 group by b.m_group, b.m_code, a.s_id, s.id_sk;
```

Plan:

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS       86763   1           169
 HASH GROUP BY                          86763   1           169
  HASH JOIN                             86762   1           169
   TABLE ACCESS FULL    TBL_MAP         2       1717        92718
   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 79688   300133251   34515323865
    TABLE ACCESS FULL   TBL_SHEET       5       912         18240
    BUFFER SORT                         79682   329274      31281030
     TABLE ACCESS FULL  TBL_VARIOUS     87      329274      31281030
```

Group by is too slow... How does it speed up?

Comment: Have you tried an outer join for table `tbl_map`?

Comment: Btw, what is the point of the `to_number(a.nums)` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any row in `b` that has `null` values in all the coalesce'd columns and is `not null` in `b.sect` and `b.m_code` will match any row in `a`, ie do a cartesian join.

My guess is that this is causing the problem. Even if there actually are no such rows in `b`, the optimizer may go for the cartesian join.

You may be able to avoid this by adding

```
and (b.part is not null or b.nums is not null or b.intersec is not null or etc... )
```

Also, its always a good idea to keep your statistics up-to-date (though I'm not enough of an Oracle expert to know how to do that).

---

EDIT: This is functionally identical and might work better:

```
and (b.part = a.part or b.nums = a.nums or b.intersec = a.intersec or etc... )
```

This will make sure that at least one value matches.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have a `CARTESIAN JOIN`, it could indicate that you missed a join condition when you wrote the query.  Please check your joins, see if you missed one.

Answer (score 0):

Given the presence of those COALESCE invocations in the WHERE clause I honestly don't know if this can be sped up.  However, hope springs eternal...  Try adding the following indexes and see what happens:

```
TBL_VARIOUS
  PART
  NUMS
  INTERC
  SEGMENT
  ACOUNTRY_MIDAS
  ORIG_NAME
  FACT
  S_ID

TBL_MAP
  PART
  NUMS
  INTERC
  SEGMENT
  ACOUNTRY
  ORIG_NAME
  FACT
  SECT
  M_CODE
  (M_GROUP, M_CODE)

TBL_SHEET
  M_CODE
  ID_SK
```

Share and enjoy.